# complex rank-one update

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the eigendecomposition of a rank-one update to a complex matrix $D + uv^T$. The matrix $D$ is diagonal, but not the identity. It has unique imaginary entries along the diagonal. $uv^T = -uu^T$, so I can set $v=-u$ and keep the vectors real, or take $u' = v' = iu$ and calculate $D + u' u'^T$. The literature I've looked at (Golub/van Loan, Horn/Johnson) concerns real matrices, but if I map the imaginary diagonal component of the matrix onto a real vector space, it becomes antisymmetric, so I wouldn't be able to use Bunch/Nielsen/Sorensen. Does anyone know about rank-one updates to complex matrices?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a result for $D$ with pure imaginary eigenvalues, not necessarily a general complex matrix, correct?

Comment: For me, it would be enough to solve for the case where the eigenvalues of $D$ are purely imaginary. If a more general solution exists, though, it would probably be useful to people searching for this topic in the future.